# flatMap a disjunction with a ValidationNel

Tags: scala, scalaz

I need a combinator that flatMap a disjunction (`\/`) with a `ValidationNel`.

Here is my attempt :

```
def flatMap[A, B, C](d: \/[A, B], f: B => ValidationNel[A, C]) : ValidationNel[A, C] =
  d.leftMap(_.wrapNel).flatMap(f(_).disjunction).validation
```

Is there a more elegant solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just fold over the disjunction in this case—it's more concise and creates fewer intermediate values:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def flatMap[A, B, C](
  d: \/[A, B],
  f: B => ValidationNel[A, C]
): ValidationNel[A, C] = d.fold(_.failureNel[C], f)
```

You could also import `Validation.FlatMap._` and then use `d.validationNel.flatMap(f)`, but I wouldn't recommend it. I like the fact that Cats has an `andThen` method on its validation type that's like `flatMap` but without the sugar-y name—I wish Scalaz had something comparable.